# Specifying input width in c

Tags: c, scanf

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction as I'm trying to write a program that takes input from a user at a prompt. Example.

> ```
> myPrompt >> {user types commands here}
> ```

However if the user presses the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, it deletes the `myPrompt` text. What I'm trying to achieve is the same as shells like cmd.exe or Bash; if you're at a command prompt and you hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, it doesn't delete the prompt text i.e. 'myPrompt' or 'C:\' etc, you can only type commands.

I've been experimenting with `scanf("%5s", input);` to no avail.

Comment: Why do you have `|` symbols surrounding your format?  Do you expect the user to type those?

Comment: Perhaps unbuffered input?

Comment: Not sure what they're used for as I've been reading other posts trying to figure it out.

Comment: Can you post the code, specifically the loop encompassing the scanf?

Comment: I've re-edited my post which makes things a lot clearer. thanks for everyones replies.

Comment: " if the user presses the backspace button, it deletes the 'myPrompt' text." This should not normally happen. Can you post a very short example program that demonstrates this behaviour?

Comment: Have you thought of using the [GNU Readline library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)? Your problem sounds more like something related to terminals/consoles (see [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) or [conio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h)) then `scanf`.